# request facebook v2.2 api with scribe for authorization

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, scribe

facebook api v1.0 expires on April 30, 2015:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

We're using scribe (currently version 1.3.6) to do a login via facebook. We need to update to Facebook api v2.2, or later than v1.0

Does scribe support connection to facebook api v2.2 ?

If i look on the generated url which is sent to the user,
v1.0 version:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=12345678901&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Findex.facebookoauthconnect%3Aauthorize&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday

If i understand right, i connect to the v2.2 api by including /v2.2/ like the following
v2.2 version(?):
...facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/...

Is that correct? At least this works for our scenario.

The URLs to facebook are defined in:
org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
and are not manipulated later in the code, so that i think scribe supports only v1.0 facebook api. Is that correct?

Is it enough to insert the /v2.2/ into the url by ourself to connect to the v2.2 api?

Kind regards
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: I **never** used Scribe since I have my own library written in-house*.

The OAuth authorization process on Facebook hasn't changed, it's merely the API. Therefore, your request path will not be on `/{object}/` (if using Facebook v1.0) but rather appended `/v2.2/{object}/`.

Scribe library merely allows you to do OAuth to the service providers easier for you. It **does not** link to ANY service providers specific API's, so you're free to change the API request path as you wish.

You will need to refer to the latest [Graph API reference doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2).

Example:

```
// getting user profile
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                                  .provider(FacebookApi.class)
                                  .apiKey(YOUR_API_KEY)
                                  .apiSecret(YOUR_API_SECRET)
                                  .build();
OAuthService service = facebookServiceProvider.getService();
OAuthRequest oauthRequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me"); //See how this link is appended with v2.2 path!!!
service.signRequest(accessToken, oauthRequest);
Response oauthResponse = oauthRequest.send();
System.out.println(oauthResponse.getBody());
```

I suggest learning the [upgrading changes from Graph v2.1 to Graph v2.2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading). You shouldn't worry about authentication process but rather the Graph URL.

Comment: Thanks Buhake Sindi for suggestion. Indeed, it was our fault, that we've manipulated the url already. Now we point to "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/".
In our dashboard at facebook https://developers.facebook.com/apps/upgrade/, i now see that % of API Calls in v2.x increased to 52%.
Before i also see 56%, but it does not increase anymore. From today only 72 days are left.
Is there any possibility where i can review the requests our server is sending to facebook api in order to identify which requests are wrong?

Comment: For that, you will have to log the request sent to FB and response returned by FB in your application.

Comment: Actually this is what we did for some weeks and from our sight, we only see outgoing requests to api 2.2. We're highly interested to know what requests facebook api receives from us which are not api 2.x. Any chance to visualize ingoing requests to facebook api?

Comment: That, I cannot help you. You will have to liaise with FB  engineers. You can examine your code base and check where all FB calls are done in your application and verify whether they're FB v1 or v2.x.

Comment: Thanks for support, Buhake Sindi. Of course it was our fault. There is some dead code in the frontend, taking the fb js lib and request api v1